# Using the Close() function with WPF versus not using Close()

Tags: c#, wpf

So this may be a noobish type of question but here is what I'm wondering.

Let's say I have two screens, the first screen is idk, **Screen1** for example. Let's say the user hits **OK** on **Screen1** which takes them to **Screen2**.

What I'm currently doing is *closing* the first screen ( **Screen1** ) so that the screen isn't in the background because the user will no longer need that screen nor should they be able to go back to that screen.

My question are essentially is these:

- Let's say that I *didn't* close that previous screen in the background, how will that effect the program?
- Will it slow the program down, because that screen is still running or will it not effect the program at all?
- I'm just thinking in terms of efficiency. Does it really matter if I don't *Close();* that previous screen?

Comment: Sounds like you need Wizard

Comment: Something like this: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wizard

Comment: I'm just wondering if I'm making the program work harder than it needs to if I leave the previous window open.

Comment: The link you provided is unrelated to my question.

Comment: I was just suggesting you think into different directions if you have windows opening one after another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is of course some amount of overhead in having a window open. It will receive various window messages from the operating system and process them. However, if the window is not really *doing* anything, then the overhead is insignificant. For example, you can open 20 copies of the Windows calculator and not see any noticeable degradation in your computer's performance because those windows are not really doing anything until you interact with them.

Basically, the difference between closing the window vs not is insignificant (unless the window is running animations or playing a video or something else causing it to change regularly).

So, you should probably be making the decision as to whether to leave the window open or not based on the desired user experience for your application. Since you stated that the user should never go back to that screen, then it probably makes sense to close it, but that is really up to the application designer (or whoever is thinking about the user experience for the application).